Auth.js v5 Google login in the production environment redirects to https://localhost after logging in success
this is my google login action
"use server";

import { AuthError } from "next-auth";
import { signIn } from "@/auth";


export const googleLogin = async () => {

  try {
    await signIn("google",{
      redirectTo: "/",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof AuthError) {
      switch (error.type) {
        case "OAuthCallbackError":
          return { error: "Google login failed!" };
        default:
          return { error: "Something went wrong!" };
      }
    }

    throw error;
  }
};

It works well in local, and I have successfully logged in. However, after deploying it to AWS, it redirects to https://localhost:3000 after a successful login.
I have set the environment variable AUTH_REDIRECT_PROXY_URL=https://www.yourdomain.com, and also tried setting the redirect in auth.ts, but it has no work.
auth.ts
...
    async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {
      return true
    },
    async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
      return baseUrl
    },
...
}


You need
NEXTAUTH_URL="https://yourdomain.com"
AUTH_TRUST_HOST="true"

in your environment file. You also want to make sure under Google Cloud > APIs & Services > Credentials > Oauth > Authorized Javscript origins, you have an entry for https://yourdomain.com as an authorized origin, and https://yourdomain.com/api/auth/callback/google as redirect URI.
